# Is there any way to export html table into Excel working in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel, html-table

I used below code for that but its works only in Firefox.
It also not allow customize exported file name. It takes a random file name.

```
 var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
          , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
          , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
          , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            var OriginalHTML = $('#' + table + '').html();
            if (!table.nodeType) {

                table = document.getElementById(table);
                $(table).find(".EditColumns").remove();
            }
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
            $(table).html(OriginalHTML);

            //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
            document.getElementById("aExportTable").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("aExportTable").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("aExportTable").click();
            HighlightSelectedRow();
        }
    })();
```

Comment: You are out if you want it in Javascript .. You are in if you want it in PHP

Comment: A CSV file would be readable by Excel and probably be easier to program for...

Comment: An HTML TABLE can be imported directly into Excel from any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). Should work in IE10+, Chrome/Safari and Fx

```
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]); // format is part of OP's code
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  if (blobURL) {
    $("<a/>")
      .attr("href", blobURL)
      .attr("download", fileName)
      .text("Download "+fileName+" for import")
      .appendTo('#downloadLink');
  }
  else {
    $("#downloadLink").html("Please cut and paste from the table below");
  }
```

Comment: Hi Can you please let me know the defenition of format function. Blob is working fine except Safari browser for me.

Comment: Look in OP's code `format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }`

Answer (score 2):

The following code worked perfect for me with IE8+, Chrome and Firefox!
It´s the easiest way to Export HTML tables to Excel without using a blob, ActiveX-Elements or downloadify:

Just insert an empty Iframe in your HTML document:

```
<iframe id="txtArea1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Add the following function to your Script section and replace the table id:

```
function fnExcelReport()
        {
              var tab_text="<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#87AFC6'>";
              var textRange; var j=0;
              tab = document.getElementById('headerTable'); // id of table


              for(j = 0 ; j < tab.rows.length ; j++) 
              {     
                    tab_text=tab_text+tab.rows[j].innerHTML+"</tr>";
                    //tab_text=tab_text+"</tr>";
              }

              tab_text=tab_text+"</table>";
              tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
              tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi,""); // remove if u want images in your table
                          tab_text= tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

                   var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
                  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

                     if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
                        {
                               txtArea1.document.open("txt/html","replace");
                               txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
                               txtArea1.document.close();
                               txtArea1.focus(); 
                                sa=txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs",true,"Say Thanks to Sumit.xls");
                              }  
                      else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
                          sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));  


                          return (sa);
          }
```

and finally call the function:

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button>
```

or with JQuery:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function () {

            fnExcelReport();
        });
```

Comment: Yes this is wokrking. Thank you very much.

Comment: I used <button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"> EXPORT </button> not jquery. !!!. Jquery not tried.

Comment: can you please tell us how to set downloaded  table name and file name

Comment: This works fine in IE, Thanks!! But i get the data without borders, is it because all data are in a single textArea? Can you please suggest a way to get borders for all rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox supports the `HTML 5` feature `data-uri` here `data:application`

If you want to make it work across all browsers, better do it in server side and set the response `ContentType`accordingly.