# Downloading file custom name with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery [plugin](https://github.com/battatech/battatech_excelexport) to export HTML table to Excel. The downloaded file name using chrome is always `download.xls` and using mozilla firefox it is `random-string.xls`. I want file name to be created according to date. For example `23-06-2014.xls`.

Below is the custom JS block in view file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnExport").click(function () {
        $("#account_table").btechco_excelexport({
            containerid: "account_table", 
            datatype: $datatype.Table
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The documentation says this, although it's still not clear how you can change the generated filename: `ReturnUri: (Boolen), this is true in case where user needs to specify a different download file name and utilize the data file URI.`

Comment: is it a mandate to use this plugin? otherwise we can use some native javascript code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to set the `download` and `href` attributes on the link. For example

```
$("#btnExport").click(function () {
        var uri = $("#account_table").btechco_excelexport({
            containerid: "account_table", 
            datatype: $datatype.Table,
            returnUri: true
        });

        $(this).attr('download', 'ExportToExcel.xls') // set file name (you want to put formatted date here)
               .attr('href', uri)                     // data to download
               .attr('target', '_blank')              // open in new window (optional)
        ;
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to use this plugin there is an alternative javascript already written by people. I just modified it to have the name of the file instead of the default one.

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }, 
        format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
        return function (table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {
                worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
                table: table.innerHTML
            }
            var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
            var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            return blobURL;
        }
})()
```

The jquery to set the name will be:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var todaysDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    var blobURL = tableToExcel('account_table', 'test_table');
    $(this).attr('download',todaysDate+'.xls')
    $(this).attr('href',blobURL);
});
```

**Example:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpKr8/123/)

**References:**
[Link1](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/wVejP/)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048399/is-there-any-way-to-export-html-table-into-excel-working-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Great, your code works well but when we use unicode or arabic it breaks http://jsfiddle.net/RpKr8/122/ I have modified your code to fix the issue.

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/RpKr8/123/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking another question on how to change file-names on downloads, let me vary this answer to focus on this scenario:

- usage of dynamic server-file-link
- usage of dynamic download-file-names

To change the *download file-name*, we will us **an anchor** with **download** property (html5); and to change the *server-file-link* we will use a **class-name** to target the href attribute of the anchor. For some uknown reasons, I found it much easier to use *class-names than Ids* on this particular case.

Now, lets build our hypothetical html markup, the href is left out for surety:

```
<a id="download-anchor" class="generic_class_name" href="#" download="static-name.csv">Download Template</a>
```

Next, somewhere in your jQuery code:

```
//dynamically changing the server-file-link
let dynamiclink = 'dynamic-link';  //generate accordingly
$('.generic_class_name').attr('href', dynamiclink);

//dynamically changing the file-download-name
let dynaName = 'custom-name-for-file.ext'; //generate accordingly
$('#download-anchor').attr('download', dynaName )
```

I hope this helps as this question rates higher on such look-ups.